# Send facebook messages using only server with no UI

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-chat

I am looking to send a facebook message from my application server without
the need to prompt the user for input each time.
I have been looking over the facebook chat API but it only works with facebook UI
which means that the user must be prompted every time I want to use the chat.
Is there a workaround or am I missing something?

I am using JAVA on my server.

Comment: you don't wan't to use UI but then how would a message will be constructed?

Comment: but i don't think that you can send messages using `Graph API`.

Comment: I have an application on the client and I get his premission to use his username and password to generate a token. In worst case, I would let him log in every time the token has expired. All I need from the user is to write his text on the client. I then send it to the server and from there to Facebook. Thats what I want to do

Comment: you can get the text from client and get it to server but you can't send it as a message to Facebook using graph API

Comment: So how about the Chat API?
I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: I think that's feasible you can check out FB Chat API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/